# (Oracle)Skip scanning table conditionally

Tags: oracle

My goal is to get average of val column in table HISTORY only when average of val columns in MYREF is NULL.
Below is my code. Is this correct way to do this? Is there an other efficient way?
Because, actual data in HISOTY are massive and I want to sure that the scanning the HISTROY will never occur if MYREF has value.

```
CREATE TABLE HISTORY (THEDATE VARCHAR(20),VAL NUMBER);
INSERT INTO HISTORY VALUES('20170101', 3);
INSERT INTO HISTORY VALUES('20200923', 4);
CREATE TABLE MYREF (VAL NUMBER);
INSERT INTO  MYREF VALUES( NULL);

WITH MYREF_VAL AS( SELECT AVG(VAL) FROM MYREF)
,HISTORY_CAL AS (SELECT AVG(VAL) FROM HISTORY)
SELECT NVL((SELECT AVG(VAL) FROM MYREF), (SELECT AVG(VAL) FROM HISTORY)) VAL FROM DUAL
 --Expected result 3.5 which is correct
```

Comment: Is there a reason that you need to do this in a single SQL query?  Can you use PL/SQL?  Rather than doing something where you are trying to force the optimizer to behave in a very particular way, which will probably be difficult to maintain as the optimizer evolves and as future developers come along who may not fully understand the solution, this is something that would be far, far easier to accomplish, far more stable, and far more self-documenting with a simple `if` statement in PL/SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use coalesce instead, because Oracle uses `short-circuit evaluation` for `coalesce`: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions023.htm

```sql
WITH MYREF_VAL AS( SELECT AVG(VAL) FROM MYREF)
,HISTORY_CAL AS (SELECT AVG(VAL) FROM HISTORY)
SELECT 
   COALESCE((SELECT AVG(VAL) FROM MYREF), (SELECT AVG(VAL) FROM HISTORY)) VAL 
FROM DUAL;
```

Simple example:

```sql
SQL> select nvl(1, 1/0) a from dual;
select nvl(1, 1/0) a from dual
               *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01476: divisor is equal to zero


SQL> select coalesce(1, 1/0) a from dual;

         A
----------
         1
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  and, what if multiple columns should be selected instead of one column? I' have  just edited question

Comment: @soon that's absolutely different question and your updated query doesn't even query from second table. Anyway in this case you just need conditional left join or lateral, for example: `select * from a left join b on a.a=b.b left join c on b.b is not null and a.a=c.c`

Comment: But the main difference here is that oracle optimizer can choose hash join and in this case it will scan second table. Just post new question with correct query here to get full answer on this new question

Comment: Thank you  for your answer, the question restored  and new question posted